# bash loop over file mask

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, filenames

What's the proper way to do a for loop over a file mask?

E.g. if the mask doesn't expand to any file, then the loop should not run; else, it should run over all the files that it expands to.

The problem with naive approach is that if the `*` doesn't expand to anything, then the whole loop will run once as if the `*` part is an actual part of a filename (of a file that doesn't actually exist).

Comment: _file mask_? Do you mean a wildcard pattern?

Comment: @codeforester an older question should not be a duplicate of a newer one.

Comment: @cnst That's not a general rule, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/1288408

Comment: @cnst: I went by the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26255799/6862601) that had the best answers, not based on time.  The age of the question shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is:

```
for f in abc*; do if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
  # Do something with "$f"
fi; done
```

That will also filter directories out of the list, which might or might not be what you want.

If you want to keep directories, use `-e` instead of `-f`.

Another way to do it is to set the shell option `nullglob` (may not be available on all bash versions). With `nullglob` set, patterns which don't match any filename will result in nothing instead of being unaltered.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in abc*; do
  # do something with $f
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

(That leaves `nullglob` set for the duration of the `for` loop. You can unset it inside the loop instead of waiting for the end, at the smallish cost of executing the `shopt -u` on every loop.)

Comment: i think -f would also filter out symlinks

Comment: @cnst: TIAS is too short to be a comment. But, anyway, symlinks to files are `-f`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nullglob` shell option to make a wildcard that doesn't match anything expand into nothing instead of returning the wildcard itself:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in abc*
do
    ...
done
```