# How to skip the for loop when there are no matching files?

Tags: bash, for-loop, wildcard, shopt

When I loop through all the files starting by `foo` I do

```
for f in foo* ; do echo "result = $f" ; done
```

The problem is when *no file* start by `foo` I get:

```
result = foo*
```

Meaning that the loop is executed once, even if no file start by `foo`.

How is this possible? How can I loop through all files (and not loop at all if there is no file)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash loop over file mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031736/bash-loop-over-file-mask)

Answer (score 22):

You can stop this behaviour by setting [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob):

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

From the linked page:

> `nullglob` is a Bash shell option which modifies [[glob]] expansion
>   such that patterns that match no files expand to zero arguments,
>   rather than to themselves.

You can remove this setting with `-u` (unset, whereas `s` is for set):

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

#### Test

```
$ touch foo1 foo2 foo3
$ for file in foo*; do echo "$file"; done
foo1
foo2
foo3
$ rm foo*
```

Let's see:

```
$ for file in foo*; do echo "$file"; done
foo*
```

Setting `nullglob`:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for file in foo*; do echo "$file"; done
$
```

And then we disable the behaviour:

```
$ shopt -u nullglob
$ for file in foo*; do echo "$file"; done
foo*
```

Answer (score 14):

The standard way to do this (if you can't or don't want to use `nullglob`) is to simply check if the file exists.

```
for file in foo*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    ...
done
```

The overhead of checking each value of `$file` is necessary because if `$file` expands to `foo*`, you don't yet know if there actually *was* a file named `foo*` (because it matches the pattern) or if the pattern failed to match and expanded to itself. Using `nullglob`, of course, removes that ambiguity because a failed expansion produces no arguments and the loop itself never executes the body.