# Why isn't nullglob behaviour default in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, posix

I recently needed to use a Bash `for` loop to recurse through a few files in a directory:

```
for video in **/*.{mkv,mp4,webm}; do
  echo "$video"
done
```

After way too much time spent debugging, I realised that the loop was run even when the pattern didn't match, resulting in:

```
file1.mkv
file2.mp4
**/*.webm # literal pattern printed when no .webm files can be found
```

Some detailed searching eventually revealed that this is [known behaviour in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255799/how-to-skip-the-for-loop-when-there-are-no-matching-files), for which enabling the shell's `nullglob` option with `shopt -s nullglob` is intended to be the solution.

Is there a reason that this counter-intuitive behaviour is the default and needs to be explicitly disabled with `nullglob`, instead of the other way around? Or to put the question another way, are there any disadvantages to always having `nullglob` enabled?

Comment: You're also missing `globstar` which is not the default also...

Comment: Historical reasons. `nullglob` is a `bash` extension to change the POSIX-mandated behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 7 glob`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html):

> **Empty lists**
>
> The nice and simple rule given above: "expand a wildcard pattern
> into the list of matching pathnames" was the original UNIX
> definition.  It allowed one to have patterns that expand into an
> empty list, as in
>
> ```
> xv -wait 0 *.gif *.jpg
> ```
>
> where perhaps no *.gif files are present (and this is not an
> error).  However, POSIX requires that a wildcard pattern is left
> unchanged when it is syntactically incorrect, or the list of
> matching pathnames is empty.  With *bash* one can force the
> classical behavior using this command:
>
> ```
> shopt -s nullglob
> ```
>
> (Similar problems occur elsewhere.  For example, where old
> scripts have
>
> ```
> rm `find . -name "*~"`
> ```
>
> new scripts require
>
> ```
> rm -f nosuchfile `find . -name "*~"`
> ```
>
> to avoid error messages from *rm* called with an empty argument
> list.)

In short, it is the behavior required to be POSIX compatible.

Granted though, you can now ask what the rationale for POSIX was to specify that behavior. See [this unix.stackexchange.com question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204803/why-is-nullglob-not-default) for some reasons/history.

Comment: Great find with the link to Unix.SE, I suppose the reasons given there also apply to Bash and therefore answer my question about disadvantages of always having it enabled? If so I'll read it over when I get a chance.

Comment: With `shopt -s nullglob`, Writing `ls -lah *.csv` in a directory with no csv files it lists ALL files. This is also wrong, could be even worse than the default behavior of passing `*.csv` to the program. Imagine if you had a command to delete all files, or only the specified on the CLI and you pass null to it, deleting all files/stuff instead only of the filtered ones. EDIT: found answer mentioning this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204803/why-is-nullglob-not-default